# my PCA plot doesn't show separate groups, where is the error

Tags: r, pca, genetics

I did a PCA plot on snps data and I have the race of each patient
the plot doesn't show separate groups which is expected how can I debug the data or what should I make sure of[image]

Comment: 1) Self reported ethnicity is prone to errors, 2) did you used LD thinned data, did you have a look at the loadings?

Comment: I didn't look at the Linkage disequilibrium , and what is the loadings?

Comment: You should use a subset of SNPs in low LDs. If you don't, your PCs are prone to represent mainly the differences in a particular genomic region (lots of SNPs, high LD: most of the time, this the MHC).

Comment: The loadings are the coefficients attributed by the PCA to the SNPs. Analysis of high dimensional genomic data isn’t an easy game, you should take the time to learn the basics beforehand, and/or seek for some help around you.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!